# DD-WRT and native IPv6

Tags: dd-wrt, ipv6

There have been a couple of questions on this topic but as things have evolved somewhat since then, so I'm opening a new thread.

My ISP has started offering native IPv6 and I'm trying to get DD-WRT to play nice. However it does not accept the router advertisements, even if I enable native IPv6 in the web interface ([screenshot](https://oc.illunis.net/index.php/s/SwcF2skw2ZRfUJ3)).

I have found that since forwarding is enabled on the `ppp0` interface, I need to set `sys.net.ipv6.conf.ppp0.accept_ra` to `2`, which at least yields an IPv6 on the public interface. But I'm not familiar enough with the DD-WRT internals to know how to persist that setting (everything in the root filesystem is presumably lost on reboot).

Also it doesn't solve the problem of changing IPv6 prefixes: everytime the PPPoE connection is lost and re-established (about once a day), a new prefix will be assigned, making it impossible to write it down in `radvd.conf`.
Right now, just switching on `dhcp6s` doesn't do anything, i.e. the daemon runs but my hosts don't receive any address from it, maybe because it doesn't know which address pool to use.

Comment: Your screenshot link does not work for me.

Comment: Hm, sorry, works fine here. I played around with all the options and contacted my ISP. They told me that DHCP wasn't needed, only native IPv6 but I couldn't get it to work reliably with DD-WRT, only randomly after fiddling around

Comment: The prefixes on the LAN and WAN interfaces have to be different. The prefix you obtain from router advertisements on the WAN interface are only suitable for the WAN interface. I know of only two ways to obtain the prefix for the LAN interface. Either the ISP give you a static prefix to use on the LAN, or your router use DHCPv6 on the WAN interface to get a prefix delegated for the LAN interface.

Comment: Your comment made me take another shot at the problem: I just replaced DD-WRT with OpenWRT and it works now ;)

Comment: I guess you won't be spending a lot more time trying to get it work with DD-WRT then?

Comment: Probably not. I already spent so much time fiddling around with DD-WRT and now found that it works with OpenWRT on the first try, so my only incentive to switch back would be if I stumble upon any major problem with OpenWRT in the next days.